# simple adapter listview horizontal

Tags: android, listview

I want to fill a Listview with images from drawable folder, but that Listview has to be a horizontal Listview, I have seen a lot of tutorial on this, but all are about personalized Listview.

Comment: so what do you really want thou or what are you really asking a way around it or help on what you are currently doing from the tutorials you have seen

Comment: I want to a Listview with images added by me, but a horizontal Listview. I have seen other tutorials but those are with a personalized.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a ViewPager where you can add the number of fragments dynamically similar to how you populate a listview.